# What do you call this game?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary

What do you call a game played on a piece of paper in which two players write either O or X in a pattern of nine squares?

Please tell me, Thank you.

Comment: Noughts and crosses (UK) or tic-tac-toe (US).

Comment: Interestingly enough, the first game to be learned by a "learning machine", so far as I know.  Ca 1965 someone constructed the "machine" out of matchbooks and match sticks, and then "taught" it to play tic-tac-toe perfectly after what was probably several hundred games.

Answer (score 2):

In 1864 the first reference was in a British Novel "Can You Forgive Her".

> Noughts and Crosses

It was not changed to

> Tic-tac-toe

until the 20th century in **American English**.

However,

> tic tac

was used as early as the 16th century to describe a repeated ticking sound. And a version of backgammon was named after this slang.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet from [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe) :

> The game has a number of English names.
>
> **Tick-tack-toe, tic-tac-toe, tick-tat-toe**, or **tit-tat-toe** (United States, Canada).
> **Noughts and crosses** or **naughts and crosses** (United Kingdom, Republic of Ireland, Australia, New Zealand, South Africa, Zimbabwe).
> **Exy-ozys, xsie-osies** (verbal name only) (Northern Ireland).
> **Xs and Os** (Egypt, Republic of Ireland, Canada, Zimbabwe).

Answer (score 0):

It's called tick-tack-toe.

Dictionary.com:

> [*tick-tack-toe*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/tic-tac-toe?s=t): a
>   simple game in which one player marks down only X's and another only
>   O's, each alternating in filling in any of the nine compartments of a
>   figure formed by two vertical lines crossed by two horizontal lines,
>   the winner being the first to fill in three marks in any horizontal,
>   vertical, or diagonal row.

Comment: Oh! Thx so much

Comment: Interestingly, it is a game that neither player can win, providing that both players make no mistakes. It doesn't matter who goes first, or what starting position is chosen.

Comment: @Mick Hey, Mick. You're absolutely right. As you probably know, that fact saved the world in the 1983 movie *War Games*, starring Matthew Broderick.